# go function - panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

Thanks in advance for everyone's help. I've marked lines 41, 42, and 58 where the problem occurs. I have not been able to track what is throwing the error. It appears all the variables are properly assigned. I use the command:

> go run file.go 'command' 'ip address'
>   ex. - go run file.go uptime 8.8.8.8

The error is:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference  
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x54fb36]

goroutine 20 [running]:
golang.org/x/crypto/ssh.(*Client).NewSession(0x0, 0x3, 0xc42009e310, 0x10)
    /home/user/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/client.go:130 +0x26  
main.executeCmd(0x7ffce5f83a51, 0x6, 0x7ffce5f83a58, 0xd, 0x5d3077, 0x2, 0xc42009a820, 0x0, 0x0)  
    /home/user/ssh.go:58 +0x16f  
main.main.func1(0xc4200d2000, 0x7ffce5f83a51, 0x6, 0xc42009a820,   0x7ffce5f83a58, 0xd, 0x5d3077, 0x2)  
    /home/user/ssh.go:42 +0x7a  
created by main.main  
    /home/user/ssh.go:41 +0x41b
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    cmd := os.Args[1]
    hosts := os.Args[2:]

    results := make(chan string, 10)
    timeout := time.After(10 * time.Second)

    port := "22"

    var hostKey ssh.PublicKey
    key, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/user/file.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to read private key: %v", err)
    }
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to parse private key: %v", err)
    }

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "ec2-user",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
    }
    for _, hostname := range hosts {
        go func(hostname string, port string) {  // LINE 41
            results <- executeCmd(cmd, hostname, port, config) // LINE 42
        }(hostname, port)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(hosts); i++ {
        select {
        case res := <-results:
            fmt.Print(res)
        case <-timeout:
            fmt.Println("Timed out!")
            return
        }
    }
}
func executeCmd(command, hostname string, port string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) (string, error) {
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", hostname, port), config)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
defer conn.Close()
session, err := conn.NewSession() //LINE 58
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
defer session.Close()

var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf
if err := session.Run(command); err != nil {
    return "", err
}

return fmt.Sprintf("%s -> %s", hostname, stdoutBuf.String()), nil
```

}

Comment: Step one is to handle the error you are ignoring on line 57.  Most likely `conn` is `nil`, and the error returned would tell you why.

Comment: Also, you never assign a value to the `hostKey` variable and so that will bite you as well, albeit with an error instead of a panic. If you want to trust all hosts implicitly, use `InsecureIgnoreHostKey` instead of `FixedHostKey`.

Answer (score 4):

As @JoshuaKolden pointed out, you need to check the error coming out of `ssh.Dial` and then not continue if the value is not `nil`. Here's a version of your `executeCmd` function with error checking:

```
func executeCmd(command, hostname string, port string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) (string, error) {
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", hostname, port), config)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    session, err := conn.NewSession() //LINE 58
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer session.Close()

    var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf
    if err := session.Run(command); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s -> %s", hostname, stdoutBuf.String()), nil
}
```

You will of course need to adapt the goroutine that calls `executeCmd` for error handling as well. Maybe print the error message to `os.Stderr` to find out what the problem is.

The reason why you get a panic is because you have an error coming out of `ssh.Dial`, leaving the value of the variable `conn` as `nil`. If you look at [client.go line 130](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/182538f80094b6a8efaade63a8fd8e0d9d5843dd/ssh/client.go#L130) in the `ssh` package you can see that it does a method call on the pointer receiver `c` to `OpenChannel`. Normally this isn't a problem for struct methods that take a pointer receiver, but in this case `OpenChannel` is a method of the `Conn` interface that is embedded in the `Client` struct. Go panics when an interface method is invoked with a nil receiver.

Edit: A potential way to use this new version of the function in your goroutine:

```
go func(hostname string, port string) {  // LINE 41
    result, err := executeCmd(cmd, hostname, port, config) // LINE 42
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error running cmd on host %s port %s: %s", hostname, port, err)
        return
    }
    results <- result
}(hostname, port)
```

Unfortunately, you cannot send to a channel and assign to another variable in the same statement. Also, you need to check for the error and do something if it's not nil, in this case I chose printing it to standard error.

Comment: thanks for your help. I modified the goroutine to err, results := <- executeCmd with no luck. am i adding error handling wrong? I'm getting error -  multiple-value executeCmd() in single-value context

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of how to use it